# Are quotes around tables and columns in a MySQL query really necessary?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a short question about mysql query.

What is correct?

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Year='1965'
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM `Persons` WHERE `Year` = '1965'
```

Is this a personal choice or is this something what is really wrong?

Comment: Thanks for all answers and for the editing. So soon if I can I will accept an answer (But which answer should I accept?)

Comment: I tend not to use backticks unless I named a table something like "table" (which would otherwise cause an error). It makes the query cleaner. The exception is when you're using dynamically generated table/column names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if you have a table named `table`, or a column named `where`. These are reserved keywords. If you used those in your queries without backticks, they'd produce an invalid query (Of course, using reserved keywords is bad practice).

```
SELECT something FROM table WHERE where = 1;
```

vs.

```
SELECT something FROM `table` WHERE `where` = 1;
```

Comment: All answers are pretty good. But this one is the best one for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Quotes are needed if your identifiers (column, table names, operators, etc.) contain MySQL reserved words.

See here for the complete list of reserved words: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 7):

Both are correct, but the second one will ALWAYS be accepted, even when you use keywords or functions like `while` and `NOW()` that would normally be seen as operators.

Answer (score 2):

Both methods are correct, the single quotation mark indicates starts and endings of a string.

Therefore if you for example use a column alias with a space like `Birth year` then you will need to use the single quotation mark like this;

```
... WHERE `Birth year` = `1965`
```

However it is not recommended only use more then one word in the aliases.

And as @Cody Caughlan said also when you use [MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).