# MySQL 150 Error

Tags: mysql, sql

The creation of the below 2 tables are failing. Can anyone please help me?

Error is MySQL: Can't create table (errno: 150)

```
CREATE TABLE PSODEMO.APPLICATION (
    APPLICATION_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    , APPLICATION_TYPE VARCHAR(10)
    , APPLICATION_STATUS VARCHAR(10)
    , CREATE_DATE DATETIME DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL
    , MODIFIED_DATE DATETIME DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL
    , DEALER_ID INT
    , COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR(120)
    , WEBSITE VARCHAR(128)
    , EMAIL VARCHAR(64)
    , PHONE VARCHAR(32)
    , STREET VARCHAR(124)
    , CITY VARCHAR(64)
    , ZIPCODE INT NOT NULL
    , COUNTRY VARCHAR(64)
    , DEALER_STATUS VARCHAR(32)
    , REMARKS VARCHAR(128)
    , INVOICE_ID INT
    , PAYMENT_MODE VARCHAR(64)
    , INVOICE_DATE DATETIME DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL
    , PAYMENT_DATE DATETIME DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL
    , PAYMENT_STATUS VARCHAR(64)
    , PRIMARY KEY (APPLICATION_ID)
    , KEY ix_APPLICATION_Applicationid(aplication_id)
    , KEY ix_APPLICATION_dealerid(dealer_id)
    );

CREATE TABLE LOGIN (
    LOGIN_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    , USERNAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , PASSWORD VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , USER_TYPE VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
    , APPLICATION_ID_FK INT
    , DEALER_ID_FK INT
    , PRIMARY KEY (LOGIN_ID)
    , FOREIGN KEY (APPLICATION_ID_FK) REFERENCES APPLICATION(APPLICATION_ID)
    , FOREIGN KEY (DEALER_ID_FK) REFERENCES DEALER(DEALER_ID)
    , UNIQUE (USERNAME)
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table2 has this constraint

```
FOREIGN KEY (DEALER_ID_FK) REFERENCES DEALER(DEALER_ID)
```

which the `DEALER` may not exists. You need to create the the table `DEALER` before `LOGIN` table because `LOGIN` table references the `DEALER_ID` of the table `DEALER` and I assumed that is is also the primary key of the table.

one more thing, use backticks around **[MySQL Reserved Keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**

```
CREATE TABLE LOGIN (
LOGIN_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, `USERNAME` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
, `PASSWORD` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
, USER_TYPE VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
, APPLICATION_ID_FK INT
, DEALER_ID_FK INT
, PRIMARY KEY (LOGIN_ID)
, FOREIGN KEY (APPLICATION_ID_FK) REFERENCES APPLICATION(APPLICATION_ID)
, FOREIGN KEY (DEALER_ID_FK) REFERENCES DEALER(DEALER_ID)
, UNIQUE (USERNAME)
);
```

Comment: i can't see your caode.. maybe  you have error on your sql syntax right? this is because you are using [MySQL Reserved Keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). in order to skip that, you should enclosed the keywords with backtick ` ...

Comment: explained here in my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338661/are-quotes-around-tables-and-columns-in-a-mysql-query-really-necessary

Comment: Below is what am using now, with back ticks, still same issue..
CREATE TABLE `psodemo`.`LOGIN` (
  `LOGIN_ID` INTEGER ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USERNAME` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PASSWORD` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `USER_TYPE` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `APPLICATION_ID_FK` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `DEALER_ID_FK` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY(`LOGIN_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `APPLICATION_ID_FK` FOREIGN KEY `APPLICATION_ID_FK` (`APPLICATION_ID_FK`)
    REFERENCES `application` (`APPLICATION_ID`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT

Comment: I used backticks, but still the same error. Also I used the same query as you posted above. I am using MySQL 5.0 version. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition
>   that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must
>   have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the
>   referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL
>   returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error
>   message.